# Can I add new value to array argument?

Tags: php

If I have a function like this:

```
function return_array( $arg = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2) ) 
{
    return $arg;
}
```

What I want to do is: I want to add something like a "`$c => 3`", without losing `a` and `b` arguments. There is any way to do that?

Comment: Have you read the PHP tutorial on arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid *"losing"* the `a` and `b` values, you will need to specify them.

```
$result = return_array(array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
));

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was anyway to avoid specifying them again, but your answer is right anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function return_array( $arg = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2) ) 
{
    $arg['c'] = 3;
    return $arg;
}

print_r(return_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function return_array( $arg = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2) ) 
{
    $arg['c'] = 3;
    return $arg;
}
```